# fqltool replay returns authentication error

Tags: cassandra

I'm getting Authentication error when I try to run `fqltool replay`.
I tried to use `-u user1 -p password1` in the command, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to handle the error?

```
root@edi-cassandra:/var/log/cassandra/fql# ll
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root          4096 Jul  2 08:16 -p/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root          4096 Jul  2 08:16 -u/
drwxr-xr-x 6 cassandra cassandra     4096 Jul  2 08:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Jul  2 07:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra 83886080 Jul  2 08:15 20230702-08.cq4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root          4096 Jul  2 08:16 cassandra/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root          4096 Jul  2 08:16 cassandra.logdir_IS_UNDEFINED/
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra cassandra   131072 Jul  2 08:15 metadata.cq4t
```

```
$ fqltool replay --keyspace edi_test_keyspace \
    --results /cassandra/fql/logs/results/replay \
    --store-queries /cassandra/fql/logs/queries/replay \
    --target 10.15.xx.xx \
    -- /var/log/cassandra/fql/ \
    -u cassandra -p cassandra
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,809 Jvm.java:160 - Chronicle core loaded from file:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/chronicle-core-2.20.126.jar
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,849 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:44 - Took 5 ms to add mapping for /var/log/cassandra/fql/metadata.cq4t
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,877 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:38 - Overriding roll length from existing metadata, was 86400000, overriding to 3600000
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,878 SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:477 - Overriding roll cycle from null to HOURLY
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,900 InternalAnnouncer.java:42 - Running under OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu220.04 with 2 processors reported.
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,908 InternalAnnouncer.java:46 - Process id: 3815541
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,910 InternalAnnouncer.java:59 - :: Chronicle Queue :: (5.20.123)
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,918 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:38 - Failback to readonly tablestore
net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.IORuntimeException: File not found in readOnly mode
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableBuilder.build(SingleTableBuilder.java:95)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.initializeMetadata(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:421)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.preBuild(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:1029)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.build(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:319)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.lambda$replay$3(Replay.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.replay(Replay.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.run(Replay.java:92)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.FullQueryLogTool.main(FullQueryLogTool.java:65)
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,919 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:38 - Failback to readonly tablestore
net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.IORuntimeException: File not found in readOnly mode
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableBuilder.build(SingleTableBuilder.java:95)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.initializeMetadata(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:421)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.preBuild(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:1029)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.build(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:319)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.lambda$replay$3(Replay.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.replay(Replay.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.run(Replay.java:92)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.FullQueryLogTool.main(FullQueryLogTool.java:65)
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,920 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:38 - Failback to readonly tablestore
net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.IORuntimeException: File not found in readOnly mode
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableBuilder.build(SingleTableBuilder.java:95)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.initializeMetadata(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:421)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.preBuild(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:1029)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.build(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:319)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.lambda$replay$3(Replay.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.replay(Replay.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.run(Replay.java:92)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.FullQueryLogTool.main(FullQueryLogTool.java:65)
WARN  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:07,922 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:38 - Failback to readonly tablestore
net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.IORuntimeException: File not found in readOnly mode
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableBuilder.build(SingleTableBuilder.java:95)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.initializeMetadata(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:421)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.preBuild(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:1029)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.build(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:319)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.lambda$replay$3(Replay.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.replay(Replay.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Replay.run(Replay.java:92)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.FullQueryLogTool.main(FullQueryLogTool.java:65)
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,125 QueryProcessor.java:115 - Initialized prepared statement caches with 0 MB
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,137 Cluster.java:267 - DataStax Java driver 3.11.0 for Apache Cassandra
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,140 GuavaCompatibility.java:204 - Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,151 Native.java:113 - Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,152 Clock.java:60 - Using java.lang.System clock to generate timestamps.
INFO  [main] 2023-07-02 08:16:08,219 NettyUtil.java:84 - Detected shaded Netty classes in the classpath; native epoll transport will not work properly, defaulting to NIO.
error: Authentication error on host /10.15.xx.xx:9042: Host /10.15.xx.xx:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
-- StackTrace --
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /10.15.xx.xx:9042: Host /10.15.xx.xx:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ExtendedAuthProvider$NoAuthProvider.newAuthenticator(ExtendedAuthProvider.java:71)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$6.apply(Connection.java:371)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$6.apply(Connection.java:351)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:213)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:202)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:726)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onSet(Connection.java:1540)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1290)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1208)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:312)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.InboundTrafficMeter.channelRead(InboundTrafficMeter.java:38)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1304)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:921)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:135)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:546)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

> tried to use -u user1 -p password1 in the command, but it didn't work.

Are those creds the actual username and password?

Try `-u cassandra -p cassandra`, which will work if the default username/password combo hasn't been disabled.

> I noticed that when I change the authenticator to authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator in the cassandra.yaml

So you have access to the Cassandra cluster?  The easiest approach here, would be to:

- Create a new role just for this purpose.
- Grant the role access to the required tables.
- Use this role and its password when connecting from fqltool.

Comment: When I'm using the command with **-u cassandra -p cassandra** I'm still getting errors (including authentication error ) I updated my original question with the new errors ,the fql files are in place , so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Aron Although it's not a solution I noticed that when I change the authenticator to authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator in the cassandra.yaml , I'm getting the queries.

Comment: @EdiM Edit made.

Comment: Hey @Aron, I don't want to use **AllowAllAuthenticator** because it leaves my cluster unprotected (I used the **AllowAllAuthenticator**  to test if this is an authentication issue ) . **fqltool replay** command is not working with username/password

Comment: @EdiM I agree. That’s why my edit is suggesting how to get it to work within the bounds of the PasswordAuthenticator running.

Comment: Hi @Aron,I followed your steps, created a new role, grant access to the required tables but I am still getting the same errors,The **fqltool replay** command is not working with username/password .In addition, the **username/password** option in **fqltool** is not documented in Cassandra https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/fqllogging.html

Answer (score 0):

This authentication exception gets thrown because you're passing credentials to the tool but authentication is not enabled on the cluster:

```
error: Authentication error on host /10.15.xx.xx:9042: Host /10.15.xx.xx:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
-- StackTrace --
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /10.15.xx.xx:9042: Host /10.15.xx.xx:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ExtendedAuthProvider$NoAuthProvider.newAuthenticator(ExtendedAuthProvider.java:71)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$6.apply(Connection.java:371)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$6.apply(Connection.java:351)
    ...
```

You need to enable authentication on the cluster to address this error. Cheers!